# Split and flatten a list of Strings and None values using a comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Given a list which contains both strings and None values, in which some of the strings have embedded newlines, I wish to split the strings with newlines into multiple strings and return a flattened list.

I've written code to do this using a generator function, but the code is rather bulky and I'm wondering if it's possible to do it more concisely using a list comprehension or a function from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module. `itertools.chain` doesn't seem to be able to decline to iterate any non-iterable elements.

```
def expand_newlines(lines):
    r"""Split strings with newlines into multiple strings.

    >>> l = ["1\n2\n3", None, "4\n5\n6"]
    >>> list(expand_newlines(l))
    ['1', '2', '3', None, '4', '5', '6']
    """
    for line in lines:
        if line is None:
            yield line
        else:
            for l in line.split('\n'):
                yield l
```

Comment: would have been great if python supported * as an operator for lists:

(*x.split("\n") if x else None for x in lines)

However I don't think it does.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `yield from`.

```
def expand(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if isinstance(line,str):
            yield from line.split('\n')
        elif line is None:
            yield line
```

---

```
list(expand(l))
#['1', '2', '3', None, '4', '5', '6']
```

Comment: `yield from` is useful, I didn't know about that syntax (still getting used to python 3 haha).  This is basically the code from my question, though, just cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single line, but I think @Ch3steR's solution is more readable.

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(i.splitlines() if i is not None and '\n' in i else [i] 
                         for i in lines))
```

Comment: Aha!  If I work it the other way it's way more compact—see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use itertools.chain if you did the following

```
import itertools

def expand_newlines(lines):

    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split("\n") if x else [None]
                                         for x in lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`more_itertools.collapse`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collapse) to flatten nested lists:

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


lst = ["1\n2\n3", None, "7\n8\n9"]
```

**Demo**

```
list(mit.collapse([x.split("\n") if x else x for x in lst ]))

# ['1', '2', '3', None, '7', '8', '9']
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) is a third-party package.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

If you might modify list inplace then you might do:

```
lst = ["1\n2\n3", None, "4\n5\n6"]
for i in range(len(lst))[::-1]:
    if isinstance(lst[i], str):
        lst[i:i+1] = lst[i].split("\n")
print(lst)  # ['1', '2', '3', None, '4', '5', '6']
```

this solution utilize fact that you might not only get python's list slices, but also assign to them. It moves from right to left, as otherwise I would need to keep count of additional items, which would make it harder.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @blueteeth's answer but more concise by way of inverting the logic:

```
import itertools
chainfi = itertools.chain.from_iterable

def expand_newlines(lines):
    r"""Split strings with newlines into multiple strings.

    >>> l = ["1\n2\n3", None, "4\n5\n6"]
    >>> list(expand_newlines(l))
    ['1', '2', '3', None, '4', '5', '6']
    """
    return chainfi([None] if l is None else l.split('\n') for l in lines)
```

`None` is the special case so that's what we should be checking for.

This is concise enough that I wouldn't even bother writing a function for it—I just kept it in the function to confirm it works via doctest.